# Linux program used to gather installed packages, processes, listening ports, etc.?

Tags: linux, process, statistics, json, yaml

It's hard to Google this because it seems like everyone and their kid sister has written a script to gather system stats!

I once saw a mature program written that is used to gather system stats like installed packages, listening ports, users, partition information, etc. and dumped everything into one nice YAML (or was it JSON?).  I was really impressed by how comprehensive it is.

I forgot what it was called, and now I have a need for it.  Can you think of any mature programs available that does this?  I'm not looking for a monitoring system or leveraging Facter; I just need a report of a current system as whole-circle as possible.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds a lot like it just saves the output from a bunch of terminal programs... something like (in bash):

`exec 1> outfile
dpkg --get-selections
netstat
who
mount
df -T
lsblk`

Then browse through the `outfile` file. Or just `>> outfile` each command instead of redirecting stdout.